# Add LineShape programatically in VB.NET WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb-power-pack

How do you add a `LineShape` programmatically in VB.NET WinForms?

I'm looking to write something like you would for a `Label` , `CheckBox` or whatever else:

```
Dim somelabel as New Label
somelabel.Text = "Whatever"
somelabel.Location = New Point(200, 200)
Me.Controls.Add(somelabel)
```

Etc.

My purpose is to create thin dividing lines between the rows and columns of 16 Labels that form a 4x4 grid.

I appreciate that, since `LineShape` is a part of VB PowerPacks, this may present some difficulties, such as having to use `Imports ...` or, if really necessary, import a `.dll`. But I'd like to see all your ideas/solutions!

Comment: which version of .net you are using ?

Comment: Controls are always added programmatically.  If you want to find out how the designer does it, so you'll have an idea how to do it yourself, then just look at the code it generates.  Click the "Show All Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window and open the form's Designer.vb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, import the powerpacks namespace to give you access to the control:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
```

Then you could do it like this:

```
Dim startx As Integer
Dim starty As Integer
Dim endx As Integer
Dim endy As Integer
Dim yourline As New LineShape(startx, starty, endx, endy)
```

Where startx = the x starting position, starty = the y starting position, endx = the ending x position and endy = the ending y position. 
If you want to put it into a canvas, simply:

```
Dim yourcanvas As ShapeContainer
canvas.Parent = formName
yourline.Parent = canvas
```

For more information and an API reference, go to: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918067.aspx

Comment: there is more information regarding older versions on the link i have provided